# A rectangular block is completely submerged in a box.

Tags: geometry

A 40 cm × 30 cm × 21 cm rectangular block is completely submerged in a box containing water without spilling over. If the container's base is 105 cm × 60 cm, by how much did the water level rise?

I set the equation as follows:

40 × 30 × 21 = 105 × 60 × X

and got that the answer is 4 cm. I'd be happy if someone could correct my solution and answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. Assuming that the walls of the container are vertical, the water level rises by $4$ centimeters, because the total volume of the water-and-block is $40\times30\times 21$ cubic centimeters bigger than just the volume of the water.